# Write a line to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ftp

Im using a array to display some images in a website:

```
var paintingImages;
paintingImages =
    [
        {
            url: 'images/objects/ron.jpg',
            alt: 'ron'
        }
    ];
```

This js code is written in paintings.js and my main js code is written in the file main.js

I have made this website for a artist and I want to give him the opportunity to login and add pictures to his website. I'm not that good with php, but adding images to a ftp in a folder is no problem.

Because I'm using a array for retrieving the images, I need to be able to add items to the array.
This is the part where I'm stuck. I don't know how to edit a existing js file, so the next time I open the website, the items (images) will been shown.

Activexobject is not a option because it's only possible in IE.

In summary:

- I need to add a item to a array
- I need to save this into the file, so the next time the website opens, it will be shown
- I'm not verry good with php, I prefer javascript
- Can't use Activexobject because of the use of multiple browsers

Comment: So you can not just edit the file on the server?

Comment: Javascript is client side and therefore can't edit server files. You will have to use php if you want to do it that way. And for javascript to talk to php you will need to use ajax. Your best bet is to start looking into jquery for the ajax and fopen/fwrite (php) for editing server files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply modify a javascript file sitting on the server from browser side javascript.
You need to implement some server side logic.

If you don't like PHP, but like JavaScript, check out NodeJS for example.
With Node you should be able to build some lightweight serverside logic to modify your json array file with additional images.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your logic .. You need to send this data to server anyhow . and when you load your next time take it back from server and update your webpage accordingly. I would suggest use any javascript MVC framework like backbone, angular.js. it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a database.
2. Save it to a database server (You figure this out, could be via forms, xhr, websockets, etc.).
3. On page load, load the correct data for the current user.
4. Create the `$userPaintings` array (call it what you want) from the user data in PHP.
5. Then simply output a JS object in the page with PHP:

   `<script>
     var paintingImages = <?php json_encode($userPaintings); ?>
   </script>`